# Issue with command line arguments passed to function and returned as dictionary

Tags: python, class, command-line-arguments, keyword-argument

```
class Cass(object):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.top_n = "endpoint1"
        self.time_series = "endpoint2"

    def get_args(**kwargs):
        print kwargs


def main(args):
    cass = Cass()
    cass.get_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--regional', type=bool, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-tn', '--top_n', type=bool, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-tt', '--traffic_to', type=str, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-tf', '--traffic_from', type=str, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start_time', type=int, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--end_time', type=int, default=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

When I run `python cassa_revamp.py -r True -tn False -tt ca -tf ca -s 0 -e 10`, I expect all of the arguments to be printed as a dictionary because I am using `**kwargs`.  I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassa_revamp.py", line 36, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "cassa_revamp.py", line 22, in main
    cassavania.get_args()
TypeError: get_args() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You aren't passing any arguments to `get_args`.

Comment: @chepner when i do `cass.get_args(args)` i get this error `TypeError: get_args() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @chepner that gives `TypeError: get_args() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Namespace`

Comment: You have to add `self` to the methods signature. If is passed as the first positional arguments implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` is a `Namespace` object; `get_args` expects zero or more keyword arguments. You need to call `get_args` with

```
cass.get_args(**vars(args))
```

`vars` returns a dictionary of the attributes of its argument, and the `**` syntax passes the dictionary as a sequence of keyword arguments instead of a single `dict` object.

Also, `get_args` should be defined to take `self` as an argument in addition to the keyword arguments:

```
def get_args(self, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
```

Comment: the above gives `TypeError: get_args() takes exactly 0 arguments (7 given)`

Comment: this worked, thanks. i do need to ask, am I going about this in a very wrong way?  i'm simply looking to pass my command line arguments to my class for use

Comment: They should be passed to `__init__`, where you can save the ones you need for use by any other methods.